# SqlAlchemy, how to make automatic join

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I got 3 tables

```
class Article_Comment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'article_comment'
    article_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('article.id'), primary_key=True)
    comment_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('comment.id'), primary_key=True)
    child = relationship("Comment",  lazy="joined", innerjoin=True)


class Article(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'article'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String)
    children = relationship("Article_Comment", lazy="joined", innerjoin=True)


class Comment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'comment'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = Column(String)
```

I need to get specific Article with Comments. I do this like this:

```
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
result = session.query(Article, Comment).join(Article_Comment).join(Comment).filter(Article_Comment.article_id == Article.id).filter(Article_Comment.comment_id == Comment.id).filter(Article.title=='music').all()
for i, j in result:
    print i.title, j.text
```

But I want to make this query without using .join.

Can someone help me?

May be, I need to remake relationships?

Comment: *Why* do you want to make the query without using `.join`?

Comment: `lazy="joined", innerjoin=True` I think this will make join automatically. Look what sql statement sqlalchemy make when I write `session.query(Article).filter(Article.title=='music')`

Comment: The thing is, what `lazy="joined"` does and what you wrote (`session.query(Article, Comment)...`) do different things. The former will not give you a list of `(Article, Comment)` pairs. What is it that you are *actually* trying to accomplish? You've told me *how* you think you should accomplish it, but not *what*. Is it to modify the `Comment`s associated with an `Article`? Or to get a `Query` of `Comment`s associated with an `Article` so you can further filter it? Or you just need a list of `Comment`s associated with an `Article`? Or something else?

Comment: I need a list of `Comment`s associated with an `Article`

Comment: Well, then just set up a relationship on `Article`, `comments = relationship(Comment, secondary=Article_Comment.__table__, lazy="joined")`.

Comment: OK, and how will the query look?

Comment: `session.query(Article).filter(Article.title=='music').one().comments`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My thx to *univerio*

Here is the full answer

set up a relationship on `Article`, `comments = relationship(Comment, secondary=Article_Comment.__table__, lazy="joined")`

```
session.query(Article).filter(Article.title=='music').one().‌​comments
```